# Searching for nested data in JSON (Laravel)

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-query-builder

"I want to create a filter where the data is taken from nested JSON."

Previously, I had a table named history_product with the column transaction_details. I want to create a filter based on unit_details. However, I encountered difficulties when using whereJsonContains. I tried using where based on transaction_id with a query like this:

```
$q->whereJsonContains('history_product.transaction_details', ['transaction_id' => 9]);
```

With this query, I successfully obtained the expected data. However, when I made a query like this:

```
$q->whereJsonContains('history_product.transaction_details', ['place->id' => 3]);
```

OR

```
$q->whereJsonContains('history_product.transaction_details', ['place' => ['id' => 3]]);
```

The system did not return the desired data. Is there any deficiency or mistake in the query I made?

I greatly appreciate assistance from everyone. Thank you.

Here is the data structure of the `transaction_details` field :

```
[
  {
    "transaction_id": 9,
    "course_id": 6,
    "course_name": "x product",
    "qty": "100.000",
    "qty_request": "100.000",
    "weight": 7500,
    "transaction_type": 1,
    "place": "{\"id\":3,\"company_id\":1,\"type\":2,\"type_place\":1}",
    "id": 9
  }
]
```

Comment: `place` contains a string, not JSON.

Comment: did you try removing backslashed from `place` value?